# How to add a assign a value to File Field Desciption through tokens

Tags: entities

Have been struggling with this, I have a field collection that contains a selection list and will like to assign this value to a file field description in the same field collection, so the selected value becomes the file display name.

Many thanks, Peace!

Comment: can you clarify:

1) you have a "<select><option></option></select>" 
2) when a user uploads a file in the form, you would like to set the <select> value as the file name?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.
Drupal has a file description option where you can enter a description of your file after uploading it. I want this file description value to be set based on the value of another field containing a select list. Like using tokens.
The only problem is that the file description does not have any settings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use: $form['#attached']['js']  in your form preprocess to add some javascript that will set the field values.